# Django SimpleListFilter Dual Option Custom Query

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm currently trying to code a SimpleListFilter that would be required to have either 2 select field to select the current state of the filtered object and also the current range of date that this would need to be filtered on then join those 2 value to create a custom filter on the object to get the required property.

The current issue is create by the first filter which add is filter to the url and this filter isnt needed after the second filter is applied.

I also tried to pop the filter using request.GET.pop('entered_state') but python return an error :

```
In [1]: request
Out[1]: <WSGIRequest: GET '/admin/requests/request/?entered_state=completed&entered_state_at=2_week'>

In [2]: request.GET.pop('entered_state')
AttributeError: This QueryDict instance is immutable
```

Here is what i have done so far:

```
class EnteredStateFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):

   title = _('Entered State')
   parameter_name = 'entered_state'

   def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
       return (
          ('completed',  _('Completed')),
          ('denied',     _('Denied')),
          ('expired',    _('Expired')),
          ('cancelled',  _('Cancelled'))
        )

   def queryset(self, request, queryset):
       return queryset
```

class EnteredStateAtFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):

```
title = _('Entered State at')
parameter_name = 'entered_state_at'

def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
    return (
        ('today',_('Today')),
        ('1_week',_('Past 7 days')),
        ('2_week',_('This month')),
        ('3_week',_('This year')),
    )


def queryset(self, request, queryset):
    entered_state = request.GET.get('entered_state')
    today = datetime.now().date()

    if entered_state != None:
        if self.value() == 'today':
            kwargs ={'entered_{}_at__date'.format(entered_state):today}
            return queryset.filter(**kwargs)
        elif self.value() == 'Past 7 days':
            kwargs ={'entered_{}_at__date__gte'.format(entered_state):today-relativedelta(weeks=1)}
            return queryset.filter(**kwargs)
        elif self.value() == 'Past month':
           kwargs ={'entered_{}_at__date__gte'.format(entered_state):today-relativedelta(months=1)}
           return queryset.filter(**kwargs)
        elif self.value() == 'Past year':
           kwargs ={'entered_{}_at__date__gte'.format(entered_state):today.replace(month=1, day=1)}
           return queryset.filter(**kwargs)

    return queryset
```

Answer (score 0):

QueryDict instance is immutable, so you should set True to `request.GET._mutable` if you want to pop it. But below is better.

`request.GET.get('entered_state')`